# cross browser css (100% height)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, compatibility

I'm creating a website and have a problem with the way it displays in different browsers. I'm testing using Chrome, iOS and IE8. The site displays correctly in the first two, but not so in IE.

The website in question is http://www.edalemill.co.uk/

Can anyone help point out what's wrong with my CSS to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look and can replicate the issue.

I would suggest removing the

`overflow:auto;` from the `#stripper`

You have also used `body` more then once as well in your CSS, I would suggest having only one lot and tidying up your code.

Possibly consider using this as a base which should help you:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

**UPDATE**

Otherwise for your code do the following for the CSS

```
#sidebar {

position:fixed;

}
```

I would recommend making that IE8 code only though

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've removed the line you mention but it doesn't affect the height of the elements in IE. They are still not filling 100% of the browser viewport.

Comment: @user2759205 so I managed to get it working by changing the following as shown in update

Comment: whilst this forces the stripbar to become 100% it messes up the other main div 'content' - it will overlay the stripbar?

Comment: Sorry I'm afraid this doesn't work - see example at www.edalemill.co.uk/about-edale-mill.php

Comment: Shorter page example: http://edalemill.co.uk/contact-us.php (right hand column does not extend to 100% height)

Answer (score 0):

If you take out the `height:100%` on `#container` the background image fills up the rest of the text area for the [about page](http://www.edalemill.co.uk/about-edale-mill.php).

Let me know if this helped.

**Update**

It might just be easier to have another CSS tag for the content areas that scroll. The `height:100%` works on those content areas that don't scroll, however, they break on those that do. My recommendation, even though it might not be the best way, is to either make a second CSS tag for the content areas that scroll, or just simply make the image bigger.

Comment: It seems there is some conflicting CSS. If you remove the `height:100%` on the `#container` then it works on 'about', but not 'contact'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It can't be far off an optimum solution now. Your suggestion at least gives consistent results (i.e. the same) in IE and Chrome. All I need to do now is figure out how to ensure they fill 100% of the height regardless of the content

Comment: I am reluctant to have different code on each page as whether or not the page needs a scroll bar depends on many factors